# Send Email With Signature using loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to send email using loopback.io, i am able to send the mails from loopback, but not able to set the signature of the mail. The code for mail sending is 
    `MyModel.app.models.Email.send({
      to: 'foo@bar.com',
      from: 'you@gmail.com',
      subject: 'my subject',
      text: 'my text',
      html: 'my <em>html</em>'
    }, function(err, mail) {
      console.log('email sent!');
      cb(err);
    });`
Is there any way to add signature in the json
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default model (i.e. documentation [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/email.json)) does not handle any signature field.

What about just add the signature to your email body ?
Otherwise, I guess you could try to extend Email model to handle this custom field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did the same way like i added the signature in the body itself